# access mysql console in GUI mode from another computer

Tags: server, mysql, mysql-workbench

I install "mysql-server" and "mysql-workbench" in Ubuntu Server 16. I can check and work on mysql-server but unable to open workbench.

I tried to open workbench using ssh from another server but it shows an error as:

> (mysql-workbench-bin:2622): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I am running Ubuntu Server in minimal mode and want to access mysql console in GUI mode from another computer.

Is it possible if yes then How can I open it in GUI mode from another computer or web console?

Answer (score 1):

Workbench cannot run in a non graphical mode and especially not on a server machine without GUI. Every attempt to let it run from ssh is therefore bound to fail.
The solution is to install Workbench on the computer(s) where you want to work in GUI mode.  They can run in linux, MacOS or even Windows. There, start Workbench and create a new connection:
[image]

Fill in the various fields as appropriate and there you go. Do not forget to grant the necessary privileges to the 'username' you will use, as explained by Rakesh.

Comment: I tried it but unable to connect. What configuration is required to do on mysql-server and workbench?

Comment: Could you be more specific when you sau you were not able to connect?  Could you at least go as far as the window I showed?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to portforward your mysql port on the ssh/mysql server and connect to it locally through MySQL Workbench:

```
ssh -l username sshserver.com -p 22 -N -f -C -L 3322:127.0.0.1:3306
```

Replace sshserver.com with your ssh host. With the above example you would then set up a new database connection in MySQL workbench by connecting to `localhost` on port `3322`

This of course presumes your ssh server is the same as your db server. If not replace 127.0.0.1 with your db server, again presuming the later is reachable from the former.

Argument summary ([from here](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2011/01/command-line-ssh-tunnel-port-forwarding/)):

```
-l login name
-p remote host port 
-N do not execute a remote command
-f requests SSH to go to background
-L port:host:hostport 
-C compression – optional
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow remote access of MySQL Server. Follow below steps to allow MySQL remotely.

Open "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" file and change "bind-address" parameter from 120.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 or your Server IP. Restart MySQL service then login into MySQL Server with terminal and execute below command which provide permission to access user remotely.

1. grant all privileges on *.* to root@'%' identified by 'mypasswd';
2. grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by
       'mypasswd';
3. flush privileges;

Now connect MySQL Server from client / other machine with Server IP.

If you have latest MySQL (5.7) version then you need to change parameter in "/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf" file.